# Can I use grunt/gulp to pull a specific version of bootstrap css

Tags: twitter-bootstrap, gruntjs, gulp

I'm working on a build process that will compile bootstrap css with my overrides.  I would like to specify a version of bootstrap in my config and have grunt/gulp go and get the .less files for that version and then compile them.  Is there any plugin or process to have grunt/gulp download the .less files for me?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I think you should use a package manager as Bower (http://bower.io/).

Grunt/Gulp should not be used to download a third-party library.